# How to malloc a table in c?

Tags: c, malloc

I'm new to C and am trying to wrap my head around using malloc. I get the importance of using/freeing them but I can't seem to grasp on how to allocate and access them.

Let's say I have a table containing 2 columns of strings with a max width of 10 for column 1 and 8 for column 2. And let's say the number of rows is 3 like the example below. How do I go about creating a malloc to hold the table of values and how do I access it's respective values?

```
["Turquoise"]["color"  ]
["Tornado"  ]["weather"]
["Triangle" ]["shape"  ]
```

Any help in illuminating this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preferred method:

```
    char ***table = malloc(rows * sizeof(char **));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        table[i] = malloc(cols * sizeof(char *));
```

It indexes as `table[row][col]`

but if cols is a compile time constant we can do better and allocate it all at once:

```
    char *(*table[cols]) = malloc(rows * sizeof(char *[cols]));
```

Technically there's a way to do this w/o `cols` being a compile time constant, but I strongly advise against it. Memory isn't expensive enough for it to pay off anymore.

Comment: bear with me on this :P

In the preferred method using my values, it should look something like this:

int rows = 3;
int cols = 2;
char ***table = malloc(rows * sizeof(char **));
for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    table[i] = malloc(cols * sizeof(char *));

If that is correct, where do I specify the size of each column or don't I need to do that?

Comment: @SureshKumar: Is not `cols` the size of each column? Or do you mean the size of each string. I normally stuff strings with `strdup()`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining.. I think strdup is a little too much for me to absorb at the moment but I managed to get malloc allocations working as per your example with an added 3rd malloc for the string value and using strcpy to fill them up. This opens new questions in my quest to learn C which I'll post in a new question. :)

Answer (score 0):

You may do it using malloc like this:

```
char **array;
int rows,cols;
array=(char **)malloc(rows*sizeof(char *));
for (int i=0;i<row;i++)
{
   array[i]=(char*)malloc(cols*sizeof(char));
}
```

Comment: This confuses me a little.. how do I assign & access values for row 0 column 0 and row 0 column 1 separately?

Comment: @SureshKumar Just like how to assign and access with 2D array.                       assign: array[0][0]=... array[0][1]=...   access: array[0][0] array[1][0]